# Jquery changes textbox border but only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I tried to add a validation using normal jquery and was successful for the first half. When I submit the blank field the textbox border changes to red, but when I fill the value and again click the button, the border doesnt changes to the new colour. Please find my jQuery Code below:

```
 if ($.trim($("input[id$='prgIDText']").val()).length < 1) {
            errMsg += "Program ID cannot be blank <br/>";
            $("input[id$='prgIDText']").css("border", "2px solid red");
        }
        else {
            alert($.trim($("input[id$='prgIDText']").val()).length);
            $("input[id$='prgIDText']").css("border", "border:1px solid #CCC");
        }
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Does your input field is dynamicaly redrawn?

Comment: No the input already exists, its a server side control of ASP.

Comment: I have no idea what fiddle is..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have border in your 2nd CSS Value.

```
.css("border", "border:1px solid #CCC");
```

should be:

```
.css("border", "1px solid #CCC");
```

See this working JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/0jvscr2n/

Comment: This is a correct fix. But i would advise not to se css thru jquery. you should toggle a class that handles the styling of your border.

Comment: I do agree with @LaurensKling. Using css classes allows you to change more with less effort.